# ActionScript - how do you get the max day in the current month

Tags: actionscript

In ActionScript, how do you get the day number at the end of the month?

- June Example

  *getEndOfMonth()* returns *30*;
- July Example

  *getEndOfMonth()* returns *31*;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many languages, you can achieve this by getting a date value for the zeroth day of the following month, then working it out from that. So maybe try:

```
var d:Date = new Date(2009,7,0);
var day:Number=d.getDate();
```

If that doesn't work, you can get the first day of the following month, and subtract a day

```
var millisecondsPerDay:int = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var d:Date = new Date(2009,7,1);
d.setTime(d.getTime() - millisecondsPerDay);
var day:Number=d.getDate();
```

Comment: Since I won't always be running in July, I changed that to        var d:Date = new Date();
       d.setMonth(d.getMonth()+1);
       d.setDate(0);
   var day:Number = d.getDate();
Ugly, but works.  I wonder if there is something better... whatever.  Thanks, even if you look like this guy from my uni rugby team that used to punch me randomly.

Comment: This is something that happens once when the app loads, not all the time.  Technically, action script months start at 1, but I know what you mean.  For some apps it's worth doing arrays and sometimes not so much.  In my case, the calc'ed answer is fine, sometimes it would be better to do the array.

Comment: The first solution relies on an undocumented implementation detail of Date's constructor. Strictly speaking it is invalid use of the Date API. The ActionScript reference at http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Date.html#Date() clearly states that the date argument must be a value between 0 and 31. While this is unlikely to change in the future, I'd be wary to use this.

Answer (score 3):

```
static public function getEndOfMonth(month:uint, isLeap:Boolean = false):uint
{
    return [31, 28 + isLeap, 31, 30, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31][month];
}
```

You can add an object called Month with const uints, for example `Month.JANUARY == 0` and so on, encapsulate it etc etc...

Comment: I still don't want to be writing date logic, but thanks for the 110%... +1 anyways.

Answer (score 0):

There are only twelve of them (and one special case for leap years)--it wouldn't be that bad to just write it out.

Comment: Technically that is not a correct statement. A leap year is every 4 years except only century boundaries that are evenly divisible by 4. So you are correct except centuries that are evenly divisible by 4 are leap years, those that are not are not. i.g. 2000 was a leap  year 1900 was not, 2100 is not. This becomes important for dates far in the past or the future.